# How to add a sort of overlay on top of every activitiy

Tags: android

My app is finished and done. Now the client wants to have a demo functionality. So when running in Demo mode there must be on every screen the tekst "DEMO" in the left corner.

How can I do this by changing minimum of code?

I see solutions with relative layouts and stuff but then I need to change every activity layout?

Comment: no,  create a base Activity,  all your Activities should extend that base Activity all you need in base Activity is to override setContentView in such a way it adds a TextView at the corner

Comment: I already use that structure of base activity and base fragments. Do you have a example of overriding like that?

Comment: no,  but did you try to call super followed by addContentView?

Comment: This is what I've got now.     @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        addContentView();
    }

Comment: and? what do you see?

Comment: Thanks working. See my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pskink I've found the solution.

In my baseActivity I override my setContentView like this:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
super.setContentView(layoutResID);

if(config.isInDemoMode()) {
    RelativeLayout lContainerLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    lContainerLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView mCustomView = new TextView(this);
    mCustomView.setText("DEMO");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lTextViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lTextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    mCustomView.setLayoutParams(lTextViewParams);
    lContainerLayout.addView(mCustomView);

    addContentView(lContainerLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
}
```

Comment: just addContentView( mCustomView, lTextViewParams) nothing more